# Applescript: decimal sign issues with different Locales

Tags: internationalization, applescript, locale

We are based in Switzerland, but have customers in Germany and Austria (this is relevant, as we will see below).

We have an application where we control Photoshop using an Applescript calling various JavaScripts. In some cases, we immediately write the return value of the JavaScript into a variable, as in

set myVar to (do JavaScript "pathToMyScript.jsx) -- pseudocode

This works very well, and we always have strings.

The problem occurs when the returned string represents a number with a decimal sign (for example "0.0184528"). The easiest is multiplying with 1, as in

set myNextVar to myVar * 1

This works all well, as long as the locale is either English, or Swiss German. But when the locale is German (or French). In this case, Applescript no longer accepts the input and throws an error.

And here, I am looking out for a good idea about dealing with the situation…

• changing the locale on the respective computer via the Language&Region System preference --> Advanced… --> General --> Number Separators is out of question; we can not expect our users to take care of that.

• temporarily changing the locale using the control Applescript (together, if needed, with System Events) may be an option. But would that work immediately, and for the script invoking the change?

• Because of the use of System Events to access active elements, the application has to be registered with the accessibility security settings. Using an applet instead is easier, because that applet does not change very frequently.

That's about what came to my mind. Are there other approaches? Anything possible within Applescript (keeping in mind that the solution has to work independent of the locale.

Any helpful idea is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an idea of why this generates an error when set to German or French? I'm sure there are others, like me, that don't understand the reason for the error.

Comment: A reason I would say is that Apple over-localized Applescript and the system. And by that over-localizing, they lost it (although that's nothing new; in the olden days, you could tear down your PostScript printer because of that over-localization)

Answer (score 2):

My belief is that your issue is coming from the different way numbers are represented in different countries. example 1,029.42 vs 1.029,42 Since you are returning a string formatted as "0.0184528", but then you are trying to coerce that string to a number, when the language is something that expects the format to be different, you get your error. One approach might be to change the string when appropriate. Find "." and replace with ","

On my "English" system this is what I would do

```
on run
    set myVar to (do JavaScript "pathToMyScript.jsx) as number-- where your script would return something like "0.0184528"
end run
```

If I were to change to "French", I believe it would give an error because it wouldn't understand that "0.0184528" was a decimal.

Interestingly enough, on my "English" system, when I changed the string from "0.0184528" to "0,0184528" and formatted it to a number, it worked.

On "English" system

```
set myVar to "0.0184528" as number -- WORKS
set myVar to "0,0184528" as number -- ALSO WORKS
```

When I change my language to "French"

```
set myVar to "0.0184528" as number -- FAILS
set myVar to "0,0184528" as number -- WORKS
```

It seems to me that representing your decimal string with a comma will work better for you. There is probably a more appropriate way to deal with this issue, but I'm unaware of it. I would at least recommend giving it a try.

**Summary of suggested test**

Try updating your javascript to return the string formatted with a comma instead of a decimal point.

Example strings that could be returned from your javascript

"0,0184528"

"39204,09"

"39203032,0502

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I am not happy with that approach, but if there is nothing better, I'd have to go back to the JavaScripts and change the return string; no big deal there. Now, if I only knew the address at Apple where I could send a Durian…

Comment: @MaxWyss - You could also consider a string replace once you get the results from the JavaScript

Comment: After some mulling over the issues, the kind and use of the numbers involved made me go for a somewhat simplistic solution: As the numbers actually have only 2 significant digits after the decimal sign (such as percentages), I multiplied the results with 100 and rounded. With that, the scripts have to deal with integers, where the decimal sign issue is non-existent. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @MaxWyss - It's funny you landed on that solution as I had thought about suggesting something along those lines at one point. Glad you got it working - Cheers!